# Connecting Session from a repeater's item to another page doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, redirect, textbox, repeater, items

I want to take the text in the text box from the particular item in the repeater that was clicked, and use it on the page ViewRecipe2.aspx.
Currently, when you click a button on one of the items, it returns back to the repeater's page, but the repeater does not appear, instead of moving to the page ViewRecipe2.aspx.

This is my repeater in aspx:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterR" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="wrapper">
         <table>
             <div class="box">
                  <div class="property-card">
                      <div class="property-image">
                        <div class="property-image-title">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="property-description">
                      <asp:Button CssClass="h5" runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text=<%# Eval("recipeName")%> BackColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent"/>
                      <p><%#Eval("avgRating") %> stars</p>
                      <asp:Image class="img" runat="server" src=<%#Eval("recipePic") %> />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="hiddenTB" runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("recipeName")%> Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This is the code behind on c#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RepeaterItem item = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
            string VR = (item.FindControl("hiddenTB") as TextBox).Text;
            if (VR!=null)
            {
                Session["selectedRecipe"] = VR;
                Response.Redirect("ViewRecipe2.aspx");
            }
        }
```

This is ViewRecipe2.aspx:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string theRecipeName = (Session["selectedRecipe"]).ToString();
                TextBoxP.Text = theRecipeName;
            }
        }
```

Comment: my guess would be that "VR" is null, could breakpoint to see if its hit

Comment: I tried removing the "if (VR!=null)", it still gives the same result, just doesn't redirect to the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, text box or hidden field is "never" null.

but, you need quotes around that "text" setting of the hidden field.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="hiddenTB" runat="server" 
       Text='<%# Eval("recipeName")%>' Visible="false">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

Also, keep in mind, that with visible=false, then the markup is NOT sent nor rendered client side. This means that client side js code can't use that text box, but server side code can just fine grab the textbox, and then the value as you have.

However, while you "should" have those single quotes?

it should still have worked.

I would for testing, remove the Visible="false", and then you can actually see + verify that the value is correct.

Comment: I tried your idea but it still doesn't work, I also tried removing the Visible="false" - it does show the name of the recipe, it's just that when I click the button it doesn't take me to ViewRecipe2.aspx. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Well, before you jump/navagate to the 2nd page, does the click event get and obtain the correct value of that control? Remember, as per that above example, the control in question needs a "id" and also needs a runat="server" fto enable the code behind to pick up that row and values. Your posted code to get the row looks fine. So, you want to double check that the VR has the correct value. Once you verify that, then the response.redirect should also work (unless the other page needs some path name).  So, before you run, put a break-point in the table